# What is the Snowflake alternative to unpivoting data like Hive's LATERAL VIEW STACK?

Tags: sql, hive, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to port Hive's version of SQL to Snowflake. The hive script consists of the `LATERAL VIEW STACK ()` function. How can i unpivot multiple columns with aliasing on snowflake? I've provided an example below.

```
SELECT 
    t.date,
    t.country,
    t.Metric_Name,
    t.Metric_Category,
    t.Metric_Numerator,
    t.Metric_Denominator 
FROM table -- containing dimensions and metrics
LATERAL VIEW STACK (4,
    date, country, "Metric 1", "Metric Category 1", metric_1_num, metric_1_denom,
    date, country, "Metric 2", "Metric Category 1", metric_2_num, metric_2_denom,
    date, country, "Metric 3", "Metric Category 2", metric_3_num, metric_3_denom,
    date, country, "Metric 4", "Metric Category 2", metric_4_num, metric_4_denom
    ) t as date, country, Metric_Name, Metric_Category, Metric_Numerator, Metric_Denominator;
```

The `Metric_Denominator` = metric_num+metric_denom.

**Sample Data**
[image: sample]

**Unpivoted Output**
[image]

Comment: I would suggest that your provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.  There are lots of reasons for this.  For instance, perhaps what you can do can easily be implemented, but there is no generic replacement for the functionality you want.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i've updated with the sample data and required output. I tried your method but i was faced with an error on snowflake : Processing aborted due to error 300002:4143448929; incident 8579664.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unpivot the data in Snowflake, I would recommend using a lateral join:

```
SELECT t.date, t.country, v.*
FROM table t CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (VALUES ('Metric 1', 'Metric Category 1', t.metric_1_num, t.metric_1_denom),
             ('Metric 2', 'Metric Category 1', t.metric_2_num, t.metric_2_denom),
             ('Metric 3', 'Metric Category 2', t.metric_3_num, t.metric_3_denom),
             ('Metric 4', 'Metric Category 2', t.metric_4_num, t.metric_4_denom)
    ) v(Metric_Name, Metric_Category, Metric_Numerator, Metric_Denominator);
```

Note that lateral joins are part of Standard SQL.

You can use `union all` as well:

```
SELECT t.date, t.country, 'Metric 1', 'Metric Category 1', t.metric_1_num, t.metric_1_denom
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT t.date, t.country, 'Metric 2', 'Metric Category 2', t.metric_2_num, t.metric_2_denom
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT t.date, t.country, 'Metric 3', 'Metric Category 3', t.metric_3_num, t.metric_3_denom
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT t.date, t.country, 'Metric 4', 'Metric Category 4', t.metric_4_num, t.metric_4_denom
FROM t;
```

Comment: I tried your method but i was faced with an error on snowflake : Processing aborted due to error 300002:4143448929; incident 8579664..

Comment: @JoelAndrews . . . This is strange.  That is a run-time error and this is a pretty simple query.

Comment: I get the same error when working with a simpler dataset. Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: Did anybody get this to work? I am trying to do the same thing and keep getting:
Invalid expression [T.field_name] in VALUES clause